# Scrolling issue on mobile

Tags: html, css, reactjs, mobile, grommet

I have a problem with scrolling on mobile. Generally, imagine a page which has a height more than `100vh` (i.e. it needs to be scrolled). When on mobile the scroller does not show until you try scrolling very gently. Otherwise the content gets overlayed by navigation bars and etc. The issue exists both on `iOS` and `Android`. However on `iOS` is a lot more annoying.

I am using `React` and `Grommet` and this is the parent box of the page content - `<Box direction="row" style={{ position: 'absolute', minHeight: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>`.

Actually, if I change `position` to `absolute` the scroller works as it is expected but this breaks other things, that would be hard to manage with `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `overflow:"auto"` or `overflowY:"auto"`

Comment: Did not really change anything.